# Jenkins docker plugin issue >> All nodes of label ‘agent’ are offline

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, containers, devops

[ 1.1.9 ] docker-plugin version

[ Jenkins ver. 2.204.2 ] jenkins version

[ 19.03.6 ] docker engine version

Connect method >> attach docker container

Hi, im trying to use docker plugin in my env. It was working everything was good. After recreating /srv/docker (i've changed the default docker path) path it stopped work.
Now when i run build i see in build logs :

All nodes of label ‘second-docker-agent’ are offline

I did "test connection" in docker configuration, it succeed.
I can also run containers from jenkins master to docker host via remote api.

Cant figure out what else i can check to troubleshoot it.
Maybe you got this issue during your expierence.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed.

I just recreated docker host configuration from jenkins site.
I deleted cloud configuration and added again as the same.